# Como pongo la condicional a mi juego

Tags: javascript, alert

Gracias a un tutorial he hecho el juego de pega al topo pero tengo un problema cuando necesito que salga un mensaje cuando el participante haya hecho por ejemplo 20 topos.. quisiera que muestre un mensaje..como podría hacer esto.. please ayudenme

```
var puntos = 0;

function empezar() {

    $(function () {
        $(".items").hover(function () {
            var tis = $(this);
            tis.find(".hueco").click(function () {
                if (tis.hasClass("active")) {
                    tis.removeClass("active");
                    puntos++;
                    $("#puntos").html(puntos);
                }
            });
        });

    });

    var iterval = setInterval(function () {
        topoaleatorio();
    }, 1000);

    topoaleatorio = function () {
        var num = parseInt(Math.random() * 12);
        $(".items").removeClass("active");
        $(".items:nth-child(" + num + ")").addClass("active");
    };

}

if (puntos === 20) {
    alert("yaganaste");
}
```

Como ven en el codigo mientras golpeo al topo los puntos van aumentando..pero al final cuando hago la condicional no hace nada..si le pongo condicional con 0 si me hace caso..pero parece que no leyera los puntos que esta haciendo.

GRACIAS A SUS APORTES LOGRE HACERLO

```
var puntos=0;
function empezar(){
$(function(){
    $(".items").hover(function(){
        var tis = $(this);
        tis.find(".hueco").click(function(){
            if(tis.hasClass("active")){
                tis.removeClass("active");
                puntos++;
                if(puntos === 25){
                  alert("Usted ha ganado");
                    location.reload();
                }
                $("#puntos").html(puntos);
            }
        });
    });

});

var iterval = setInterval(function(){
    topoaleatorio();
}, 1000);

topoaleatorio = function(){
    var num = parseInt(Math.random() * 12);
    $(".items").removeClass("active");
    $(".items:nth-child("+num+")").addClass("active");
};

    }
```

Comment: Podrías depurar el código cada vez que "golpeas" el topo para comprobar si la variable está aumentando ?

Comment: tienes que poner la condición dentro del función de `click` porque esa el función que se ejecuta siempre que hace un click, y antes de aumentar los puntos puedes validar si es igual a 20 y mostrar el alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle esta que cuando se ejecuta el código js enseguida ejecuta su condicional, por eso es que nunca entrara porque valida sobre el valor inicial de puntos en este caso 0, lo que usted podría hacer es meter la condicional dentro del evento donde golpea al topo, por lo que entiendo es en este evento

```
$(function(){
    $(".items").hover(function(){
        var tis = $(this);
        tis.find(".hueco").click(function(){
            if(tis.hasClass("active")){
                tis.removeClass("active");
                puntos++;
                if(puntos === 20){
                  alert("Usted ha ganado");
                }
                $("#puntos").html(puntos);
            }
        });
    });
```

});